# not able to hide the row using switch

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am using the below code to hide the code :

```
=switch(Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="",True,
Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="1",True,
Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="3118",True,false)
```

but it is giving the below error :
An error occurred during local report processing.
The Hidden expression for the text box 'Switch_Login_Id contains error: Argument 'VarExpr' is not a valid value.
The Hidden expression for the text box 'Switch_Login_Id contains error: Argument 'VarExpr' is not a valid value.

I can use the iif function to hide the result but just curious whether we can do it using SWITCH or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try amending the default like this:

```
=switch(Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="",True,
Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="1",True,
Fields!Switch_Login_Id.Value="3118",True,
True,false)
```